# Web Scraping Image URL Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, imageurl

I am trying to scrape image URLs from   https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2019-12-28.

Here is the example (span with class = 'chart-element__image flex--no-shrink')

```
<span class="chart-element__image flex--no-shrink" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://charts-static.billboard.com/img/1994/12/mariah-carey-99g-all-i-want-for-christmas-is-you-3w0-155x155.jpg&quot;);"></span>
```

As you can see the span has a property 'style' which is showing different values from my scrape output.
see below

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_selenium_image_list(url):
    """"given a top chart URL returns image list with selenium """
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # need to install chrome with specific  driver
    driver.get(url)
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    selenium_query = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="chart-element__image flex--no-shrink"]')
    image_list = []
    for element in selenium_query:
        image_list.append(element.get_attribute('style'))
    return image_list
get_selenium_image_list('https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2019-12-28')
```

result :

```
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
display: inline-block; height: 0px; width: 0px;
....
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? and how to solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: Seems to be there are other spans in the page that matches the xpath. Try with `selenium_query = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="chart-element__image flex--no-shrink"][starts-with(@style,"background-image")]')`

Comment: Thanks, It did help but now something even stranger is happening.
I get the first 5 links , but the rest of them (95 more) are not being returned at all - not even empty strings. 
The funny thing is the prior query got me 100 results which is the number of images with the specified structure in the URL